# How to manually assign x-axis value using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

[image]I have a CSV file with 12 columns and 4,00,020 rows, I want to plot these columns in separate graphs. I want to manually give x-axis values.
x- axis = 0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6 ..., 2

How can I give the x-axis manually? I tried the below code but didn't work. Kindly help. Thanks in advance.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x= np.arange(0,2,0.2)
df.plot(x, y = 'column1')
plt.show()
```

I want the output something similar to the image above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
df.plot(xlim=(0.2,2), xticks=np.arange(0,2,0.2), subplots=True)
```

check out [the documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html)

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = [1, 2, 3, 4] 
y = [6, 10, 15, 4] #or your column
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')

plt.show()
```